# Unable to uninstall VIM installed from source

Tags: linux, installing, compile-vim

I installed VIM by compiling from source a while back following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source). At that time, for some reason, I didn't use `checkinstall`, as a result I can't uninstall it using `sudo apt-get remove vim`.

Following the advice [here](https://superuser.com/questions/623040/uninstalling-vim-compiled-from-source), I tried to remove VIM by

```
cd ~/tmp
hub clone vim/vim
cd vim
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim80
sudo make uninstall
```

Note, I am using `make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim80` instead of `make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim/vim80` as suggested by the other link. This is because that's where there is a `vim80` directory. I have also confirmed this by looking through my command line history that I indeed used `make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim80` when installing vim at that time.

After I ran the above set of commands, it seems that vim got removed, in that I can no longer start `vim` by typing `vim` in the command line. However, when I look at the output of the command, it seems its actually trying to remove the files from the non-existent directory at `/usr/local/share/vim/vim81`. I have posted a snapshot of the output here but it's the same for the rest of the output

```
rmdir /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/doc /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/print /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/colors /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/syntax /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/indent
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/doc': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/print': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/colors': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/syntax': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/indent': No such file or directory
Makefile:2776: recipe for target 'uninstall_runtime' failed
make[1]: [uninstall_runtime] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -rf /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/*.vim /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/README.txt /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/logtalk.dict
rm -f /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/*.vim /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/README.txt
rm -f /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/dist/*.vim /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/xml/*.vim
rm -f /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/plugin/*.vim /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/plugin/README.txt
rmdir /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/dist /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/xml /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/dist': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload/xml': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/autoload': No such file or directory
Makefile:2776: recipe for target 'uninstall_runtime' failed
make[1]: [uninstall_runtime] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/plugin /usr/local/share/vim/vim81
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/plugin': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim/vim81': No such file or directory
Makefile:2776: recipe for target 'uninstall_runtime' failed
make[1]: [uninstall_runtime] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir /usr/local/share/vim
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/local/share/vim': Directory not empty
Makefile:2776: recipe for target 'uninstall_runtime' failed
make[1]: [uninstall_runtime] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f /usr/local/bin/vim
rm -f /usr/local/bin/vimtutor
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gvimtutor
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ex /usr/local/bin/view
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gvim /usr/local/bin/gview
rm -f /usr/local/bin/rvim /usr/local/bin/rview
rm -f /usr/local/bin/rgvim /usr/local/bin/rgview
rm -f /usr/local/bin/vimdiff /usr/local/bin/gvimdiff
rm -f /usr/local/bin/evim /usr/local/bin/eview
rm -f /usr/local/bin/xxd
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dibya/tmp/vim/src'
```

When I looked at the folder in `/usr/local/share/vim`, I noticed that the directory `vim80` is still present.

### Question

Is it enough to just delete the `vim80` directory? Why is `make uninstall` trying to remove `vim` from `/usr/local/share/vim/vim81` instead of `/usr/local/share/vim/vim80`?

Comment: Maybe try using the commit that was likely to be the HEAD at the time you built Vim initially?

Comment: @muru.. thank you very much.. Actually I had a hunch that is what it is.. so after posting this.. I went ahead and installed the `vim 8.0` version that I had and then tried to uninstall it.. It worked.. and the folder in `/user/local/share/vim/vim80` was gone.. Perhaps its a bug.. that it doesn't respect the `VIMRUNTIMEDIR` even when specified with `make`.

Comment: Do you want to post the solution? I can accept it..

Comment: Nah, it's better if you posted exactly what you did (did you still have the old sources, and how did you get them if you didn't).

Answer (score 1):

As @muru has suggested, I will post the solution here..

The situation happened, when I was trying to debug a issue related to a plugin. It seemed to work for a colleague, but not for me. So one of the hypothesis was that it was because of the differing versions of VIM.

Because the VIM version (8.0.1430) was compiled from source, I had the exact SHA id of the VIM version written down, and I also knew the SHA ID that I wanted to install.

My colleague was running VIM version (8.1.42).

My first attempt at removing VIM, was to just get the source from GitHub, and follow the steps: https://superuser.com/questions/623040/uninstalling-vim-compiled-from-source

to uninstall VIM.

Because the command `vim` was no longer working, I thought that `VIM` had been properly installed. So I proceeded to install vim_v_8.1.0042. The vim source code from GitHub has tags associated with each release. So based on that I could figure out the SHA ide of the v_8.1.0042, and installed it.

This is when I realized the `VIM80` folder is still present.. and pretty large.. and maybe indicates that `VIM8.0` hasn't actually been completely removed. I also noticed that `VIM8.1` was being installed in `VIM81` directory. So I uninstalled `VIM8.1` properly and then proceeded to install `VIM8.0.1430`.

This left the same direction `VIM80`.. which confirmed that the version number was determining what directory `VIM` puts in the system.

After I uninstalled `VIM8.0`, the `VIM80` directory was gone as well as `vim` didn't startup the `vim` editor.

By this process I was able to uninstall `VIM80`, even though I couldn't uninstall it in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed vim using the make command then, follow the steps below to uninstall it.
Type the following commands in the terminal:

```
cd vim-master
cd src
sudo make uninstall
```

This must uninstall the vim!

**Pls note: If your installing directory is not vim-master, please navigate to your installing directory before proceeding.**